# redux , invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

When I setup and use `Provider` in `root.render` it show me this error:

> Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the
> body of a function component. This could happen for one of the
> following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app and Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')

It just for `Provider` component, if I don't call it I will not have this error.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Provider>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

I uninstalled the redux and npm package and then install them with last version but I have same problem. Someone said maybe it's for have same name in two package and it is confusing the computer but I don't think so.

Comment: Hey, what is the version of React, React DOM .
try this and let me know if it still occurs. 
npm install react@latest react-dom@latest 
Thanks

Comment: And, shouldn't there be any store in <provide> ?
<Provide store={store}></Provide>

Comment: have a good time , i did it and it is update , but still have same problem! i add the store but it dese not work.

Comment: The only issue I see in the code you've shared is a missing `store` prop for the `Provider` component. We can't help with other issues in the code you haven't shared with us. Please [edit] to include a more complete [mcve] and any error stacktrace if it's available.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `store` to the `Provider`

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from "./path/to/store"

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: it desnt work! what should i do??

Answer (score 0):

I already made a comment, but to make it more visible, I am pasting this code snippet. Let me know if there is any other issue there?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from "./store" // you need a store to provide to the provider

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

The change is in this line

```
import store from "./store"
<Provider store={store}>
    <App />
</Provider>
```

Comment: i tested it and it desnt work actually! do you have any else plan ? :)

Comment: And, let me know the package.json of your project. Thanks

Comment: my package.json is this :  {
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {"extends":  "react-app","react-app/jest}

Comment: and also i dont know how to work with this website 'codesandbox.io/s/reactredux-jfvk7' , but i know in that code you use createstore exrend configureStore  ,  thanks for your help